# How to find version of gitlab backup?

Tags: gitlab

I have a backup of unknown gitlab version. My partner assume it is created by gitlab version 6.0.2 But when I implement a gitlab version 6.0.2 I am still impossible to restore it because of mismatch version. So how do I get exactly version of a gitlab backup ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the tar archive there is a file called `backup_information.yml`. There lies the info you are looking for. To find the version number:

```
tar xf 1411831804_gitlab_backup.tar -O backup_information.yml | grep gitlab_version | awk '{print $2}'
```

Where `1411831804_gitlab_backup.tar` the archive in question.

You could also make a simple script and loop over the backup folder like so:

```
for archive in $(find /home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups -name '*.tar'); do echo -ne "$archive - $(tar tf $archive backup_information.yml | grep gitlab_version | awk '{print $2}')\n"; done
```

Where `/home/git/gitlab/tmp/backups` is the path to the backup directory. For Omnibus GitLab it is `/var/opt/gitlab/backups`.

But yeah, the tar name should be more descriptive. As a matter of fact, I was thinking the same some time ago when I migrated to a packaged installation. Will submit a patch.

Comment: You are right. I think there is no need to use a script for finding all tar in backup folder. It will take much time. I know where backup file is. Just untar and find as you said. And I agree you about tar name. Sometime I must see timestamp on files ystem to specify backup files being created at the same time. Thank you so much axil.